# Can't import to SVN local repository

Tags: windows, svn

I want to use SVN and read it's help.I follow instruction one by one.

1. Install TortoisesSVN
2. Create folder
3. Right button on this folder and TortoisesSVN->Create Repository here->Create folder structure
4. Right button on the same folder TortoisesSVN->Import
5. Add this string in dialog "file:///D:/developing/Repo/trunk/test" where Repo is the repository

And i get this error message
[image]

I search in google and can't find what I'm doing wrong.Is any one else have similar problem ?? My OS is win7

Edit
(because error message is too small):

> Error:
>   Can't read file 'D:\developing\Repo\db\txn-protorevs\1-3.rev-lock': The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Import* consists in adding a project (source code) into a repository. You invoke *Import* on the root directory of the project. Not on the directory containing the SVN repository. Importing a repository inside a repository doesn't make sense.

Read section 4.2 of TortoiseSVN's help. (right-click on any directory, TortoiseSVN - Help)